# Find the equal sets of strings and their count (distinct lists)

Tags: c#, linq, count, set, distinct

I'm trying to find the distinct sets and their count.

Say you have the following model.

```
public class AModel {
   public IList<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

And you have a list of the above model, let's say 50.000 instances of `AModel` with 1...N `Tags`.

I need to find using performant LINQ the distinct `Tags`, lists not list values (order does not matter, count and tag string matter).

Example:

```
List<AModel> models = new List<AModel>{
   new AModel { Tags = new List<string> { "Tag1", "Tag2" } },
   new AModel { Tags = new List<string> { "Tag2", "Tag1" } },
   new AModel { Tags = new List<string> { "Tag1", "Tag1" } },
   new AModel { Tags = new List<string> { "Tag2", "Tag2" } },
   new AModel { Tags = new List<string> { "Tag2", "Tag2" } },
};
```

So, I need a result of:

```
List: { "Tag1", "Tag2" } Count: 2
List: { "Tag1", "Tag1" } Count: 1
List: { "Tag2", "Tag2" } Count: 2
```

I've checked so far, SetEquals and SequenceEquals. I could iterate to all the Tags of all the Models and keep the count and the set that are equal and pass the next  if I checked it already, but it is counter efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a `EqualityComparer<IList<string>>`

```
public override bool Equals(IList<string> x, IList<string> y)
{
    return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x.OrderBy(i => i), y.OrderBy(i => i));
}

public override int GetHashCode(IList<string> obj)
{
    return obj.Select(i => i.GetHashCode()).Average().GetHashCode();
}
```

Use it in linq groupby

```
List<AModel> models = new List<AModel>() {
    new AModel { Tags = new List<string> { "Tag1", "Tag2" } },
    new AModel { Tags = new List<string> { "Tag2", "Tag1" } },
    new AModel { Tags = new List<string> { "Tag1", "Tag1" } },
    new AModel { Tags = new List<string> { "Tag2", "Tag2" } },
    new AModel { Tags = new List<string> { "Tag2", "Tag2" } },
};

var result = models
    .GroupBy(i => i.Tags, new ListEqualityComparer())
    .Select(i => new { Tags = i.Key, Count = i.Count() });
```

Comment: This way you can actually have more control and it will work better if the list is a custom object. Reminded to me, pay attention to method overloads!

Comment: obj.Select(i => i.GetHashCode()).Sum().GetHashCode(); throws OverFlowException, Number Overflow. I don't know if this somehting that has to do with Xamarin though.

Comment: @GeorgeTaskos The OverFlowException should be cause by `SUM()`, try use `Average()` instead. The rule for `GetHashCode()` is to return same value for `Equals = True` cases, and if collision, check `Equals()`

Comment: Checking this answer as correct for the detail EqualityComparer<T> answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I would approach this problem is to order the tags first then combine them to make a unique key that I can then use line to group by. The grouping should automatically provide me with the key and the count.

Here's a rough draft to get you started:

```
foreach(var value in models.Select(model => String.Join(";", model.Tags.OrderBy(tags => tags))).GroupBy(list => list))
{
     Console.WriteLine(value.Key + "," + value.Count());
}
```

The output is very similar to what you want:

Tag1;Tag2,2
Tag1;Tag1,1
Tag2;Tag2,2

Comment: I haven't thought that I could GroupBy in the List<string> property, my first thought was that. it works fine.